# Zend: set application to development stage

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework, installation

I added this line **SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development** in my .htaccess

And I have this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Config_Exception' with message 'Illegal circular inheritance detected' in C:\wamp\www\Zend_Include\library\Zend\Config.php on line 431
( ! ) Zend_Config_Exception: Illegal circular inheritance detected in C:\wamp\www\Zend_Include\library\Zend\Config.php on line 431
```

If I remove the line, the app works fine but its always in production stage. How can I change my dev stage.

FYI, I use wamp server

.htaccess

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

application.ini

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0

resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : development]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

Comment: If you have set your environment to development than try to copy the same setting from production to development this might solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to inherit development from development section.

Just change this line:

```
[development : development]
```

to:

```
[development : production]
```